# Inserting review into database, radio input doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, forms

In my site I show a list of locals and for each I have a modal that show more information. In this modal I have the possibility to see reviews from users and to insert reviews. All the information and datas are from my database.
Into the insert review form there are 3 editable fields:

- Input `type="text"` for the review title
- Textarea for the description of the review
- Input type="radio" for the rate, that can be 1-2-3-4-5 -> each of the radio input it's a different vote, so if a User click on the second radio, the rate will be 2.

With the first local, all works fine, a user can insert the review correctly. With the others locals there is a problem:

If I click on the stars that represent my rate, the user input don't work, so I can't choose the vote, and I can't insert the review, because if I click the submit button, my review won't be inserted because the vote is missing.

#### Insert review form

```
echo' <div class="col-sm-12" id="recensioni_titolo">
        <form role="form" id="review-form" method="post" action="php\insert_comment.php">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Titolo" id="titolo_review" placeholder="Titolo">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID_locale" id="titolo_review" value="'.$id_Local.'" style="visibility: hidden; position:fixed;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <fieldset class="rating form-group-">
                        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="Voto" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Ottimo - 5 stelle"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="Voto" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Buono - 4 stelle"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="Voto" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Discreto - 3 stelle"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="Voto" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Insufficiente - 2 stelle"></label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="Voto" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Pessimo - 1 stella"></label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control textarea" rows="3" name="Review" id="review" placeholder="Inserisci una descrizione.."></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn main-btn pull-right" id="submit_review">Invia</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>';
```

#### Insert_comment.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['Titolo'])) {
        $title_rew = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Titolo']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Voto'])) {
       $voto_rew = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Voto']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Review'])) {
        $review_rew = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Review']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['ID_locale'])) {
        $id_rew = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['ID_locale']);
    }
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO recensione (ID_Recensione,Titolo_R, Voto_R, Commento_R, IDnegozio_R, Email_R, Utente_R, Data_R) 
            VALUES (DEFAULT, '$title_rew', '$voto_rew', '$review_rew','$id_rew','".$_SESSION['emailSessione']."','".$_SESSION['usernameSessione']."','$current_date')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $conn->close(); 
?>
```

#### JavaScript of `#submit_review`

```
$("#submit_review").unbind().click(function() {
    var chx = document.getElementsByName("Voto");
  for (var i=0; i<chx.length; i++) {
    // If you have more than one radio group, also check the name attribute
    // for the one you want as in && chx[i].name == 'choose'
    // Return true from the function on first match of a checked item
    if (chx[i].type == 'radio' && chx[i].checked) {
            $.ajax({
            url : "php/insert_comment.php",
            type : "post",
            data : $("#review-form").serialize(),
            success : function(data){
                $.ajax({
            url : "php/reviews.php",
            type : "post",
            data: {'id_Local' : $('.modal').attr('data-modal')},
            success : function(data){
                $('#box_recensioni').html(data);
        }
})
        }
})


      return true;
    } 
  }
  // End of the loop, return false
alert("Inserisci almeno il voto!!")
  return false;
});
```

Comment: include the source of php\insert_comment.php also?

Comment: added php\insert_comment.php